# Unfortunately MyApplication has stopped

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-emulator

I am trying to start my activity from Listview items. it is working fine for first item but gives an error when I click on `SecondActivity`.
Here is my code of `ListView` activity

```
public class menu extends ListActivity{
    String [] menuItems = {"MainActivity","SecondActivity","Item2","Item3"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, menuItems));

    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        try {

            Log.d("Tst","Value");
            Class menuItem = Class.forName("com.example.newboston." + menuItems[position] );


            Intent itemItent = new Intent(menu.this, menuItem);
            startActivity(itemItent);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is Code of my `SecondActivity`

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

    EditText etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Button btPass =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btPassword);
    ToggleButton tgPass = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgPassword);
    TextView tvPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTV);
    Random animate = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      Log tag;
//      Log.d("testing", "In toggle java");
        setContentView(R.layout.togglebtn);
        passTextCheck();    
        textPosition();
    }

    public void passTextCheck(){
    tgPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tgPass.isChecked()){
                etPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }else{
                etPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }   
        }
        });
    }
    public void textPosition(){
        btPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          Toast testToast = new Toast(toggle.this);
            CharSequence text;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String check  = tgPass.getText().toString();
                if(check.contentEquals("left")){
                    tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    tvPass.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    text = "Left + Blue";
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else if(check.contentEquals("right")){
                    tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    tvPass.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    text = "Right + Green";
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(check.contentEquals("center")){
                    tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tvPass.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    text = "Center + Magenta";
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(check.contentEquals("animate")){
                    tvPass.setText("Hello");
                    tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tvPass.setTextColor(Color.rgb(animate.nextInt(50), animate.nextInt(50),animate.nextInt(50))  );
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newboston"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newboston.Startup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newboston.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.newboston.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newboston.menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.newboston.menu" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newboston.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.newboston.SecondActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There should be a stack trace in your logcat.  Please post that.

Comment: Nothing like a "here's my code. plz fix" question.

Comment: Any stacktrace available?

Comment: how check stacktrace??

Comment: @LASIAF goto windows perspective ddms logcat. there you will see the exception and also the line at which exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{  

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  Log tag;
    // Log.d("testing", "In toggle java");
    setContentView(R.layout.togglebtn);


**Changes here** 
**EditText etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
Button btPass =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btPassword);
ToggleButton tgPass = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgPassword);
TextView tvPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTV);
Random animate = new Random();**

    passTextCheck();    
    textPosition();
}

public void passTextCheck(){
tgPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(tgPass.isChecked()){
            etPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        }else{
            etPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        }   
    }
    });
}
public void textPosition(){
    btPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          Toast testToast = new Toast(toggle.this);
            CharSequence text;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String check  = tgPass.getText().toString();
                if(check.contentEquals("left")){
                    tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    tvPass.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    text = "Left + Blue";
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(check.contentEquals("right")){
                tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                tvPass.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                text = "Right + Green";
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(check.contentEquals("center")){
                tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tvPass.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                text = "Center + Magenta";
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(check.contentEquals("animate")){
                tvPass.setText("Hello");
                tvPass.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tvPass.setTextColor(Color.rgb(animate.nextInt(50), animate.nextInt(50),animate.nextInt(50))  );
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Code is same as i posted.

Comment: i change intilization of ui after setcontent view

Comment: @LASIAF you need to initialize your views after `setContentView`.

Comment: @DigveshPatel its working. Thanx. But why it was working for first item according to my code..???

Comment: @LASIAF in your mainactivity may be you were not getting NPE. But when you navigate to SecondActivity you get NPE hence the crash.

Comment: NPE mean?? @Raghunandan

Comment: @LASIAF its `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @LASIAF - You cannot initialize the android widgets(Edittext,TextView etc) before you specify the layout in setContentView method..If it doesnot find any layout, the findViewById will return null and so you get nullPointerException..

Answer (score 0):

One visible mistake. You are initializing your views outside `onCreate`. You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. You need to set the content to the activity first then initialize your views. If not you will get `NullPointerException`.

```
    EditText etPass;
    Button btPass; 
    ToggleButton tgPass;
    TextView tvPass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.togglebtn);
    etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btPass =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btPassword);
    tgPass = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgPassword);
    tvPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTV);
    .... // rest of the code
    }
```